# Kendo Grid Get the Row you are editing in edit function

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a have a kendo heiarchy grid, what I need to do is when the edit function is triggered get the current row that I am editing and then based on that row get the corresponding master row.

My Edit function

```
update: function(e) {

    var campaignWeek = e.data.models[0]

    $.ajax({
      type: 'PUT',
      data: {"campaign_week": campaignWeek },
      url: "/campaign_week",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        e.success(data);
        $(awesomeCampaignId.find('td')[4]).text(data.week_total_cost)
        $(awesomeCampaignId.find('td')[5]).text(data.week_total_impressions)
        $(awesomeCampaignId.find('td')[6]).text(data.week_total_grps)


      },
    });
  },
```

The data that I get in e:

```
object {success: function, error: function, data: Object}
```

The Grid:

```
function campaignWeekGrid(e) {

  var stationCampaignId = e.data.id
     masterRow = e.masterRow

  datasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({ 
    transport: {                        
      read: function(e) {

        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: "/station_campaigns/" + stationCampaignId + "/campaign_weeks",
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) {

             e.success(data);

          },
        });
      },
      update: function(e) {
        var campaignWeek = e.data.models[0]

        $.ajax({
          type: 'PUT',
          data: {"campaign_week": campaignWeek },
          url: "/campaign_week",
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) {
            e.success(data);
            $(masterRow.find('td')[4]).text(data.week_total_cost)
            $(masterRow.find('td')[5]).text(data.week_total_impressions)
            $(MasterRow.find('td')[6]).text(data.week_total_grps)


          },
        });
      },
      parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
        if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
          return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
        }
      },
    },
    batch: true,
    filterable: true,
    schema: {
        model: {
          id: "id",
          fields: {
          date_range: { type: "string", editable: false },
          cost: { type: "number" },
          impressions: { type: "number" },
          cost_per_thousands: { type: "number" },
        }                          
      }
    },
  }); 
  $("<div>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({ 
    dataSource: datasource,                                                
    height: 500,
    resizable: true,
    autoSync: false,
    columns: [
      { field: "date_range", title: "Week", width: "175" },
      { field: "cost", title: "Cost" },
      { field: "impressions", title: "Impressions" },
      { field: "cost_per_thousands", title: "GRPs" },
      { command: ["destroy", "edit"], width: "100" },
    ],
    editable: "inline"                                               
  }); 
}
```

I need to be able to replace the masterRow variable in my update function.  So I need to be able to get the current row I am editing and then get the corresponding master row to that row.  I have been searching for a while now and can not find a solution.  Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In a kendo grid you can get the selected row when user clicks a button:

```
// grid edit onclick function
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    var grid = $("#gridName").data("kendoGrid");

    $(grid.tbody).on("click", "td", function (e) 
    {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        var rowIdx = $("tr", grid.tbody).index(row);
        selectedRow = rowIdx;

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try below code, it worked for me.

```
var grid = e.sender;
var dataitem = grid.dataItem($(e.container).closest("tr"));
```

Please mark as answer if you found this helpful.

Thanks.